# Grammar - which tense should I use

Tags: grammar, tenses

I work with xyz pvt ltd, and I joined that company in 2011 and am still working there. I simply want to tell this to the HR Executive during the interview. What is the grammatically correct way to explain this in a formal situation?

If i say:

> I have been working there since 2011.

I think the above mentioned line means that I am continuously working there; means no break or I had not come home.

If I say:

> I am working at xyz pvt limted since 2011.

(again I think it would be grammatically incorrect).

Please tell me a correct line to explain my situation.

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-). I think that your question might be better suited on our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) (you can flag it yourself to ask moderators to migrate it). I would suggest before posting other questions to have a look at websites [help centre](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/asking) and to check whether someone asked a similar question before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i say . "I have been working there since 2011?"
>
> I think above mentioned line means that I have been continuously working
>   ... no break or I had not came home.

The sentence: "I **have been working** with XY for 4 years/ since 2011"

is perfectly alright and doesn't imply you never went home

Comment: If i say,I work at XYZ pvt limited as a Senior Executive.I have been working there since 2011.(Is this line is correct)

Comment: Ok, i am new on this site and i kept on searching for hours

Comment: Yes, it is correct, you can change any part of the sentence, the verb is always correct.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you should say "here", not "there". Otherwise it is fine.